# Chrome browser can't open file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typescript, web

I have a very strange problem with chrome browser. I try to open files (images and PDFs) in the new popup. For do that I use this function

```
window.open('data:' + type + ';base64,' + data, '_blank', 'height=300,width=400');
```

where type and data I get from the server.

So it's work perfectly in Opera, Mozilla, and Edge. 
[Popup in opera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxR1m.jpg)
But in Chrome I get an empty popup window.
[Popup in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGMTb.jpg)

May be someone knows how can I fix this, or is this chrome bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using instead of this

```
window.open('data:' + type + ';base64,' + data, '_blank', 'height=300,width=400');
```

this code

```
let byteCharacters = atob(file);
let byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
     byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}
let byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
let blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: contentType});

const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(fileURL, '_blank', 'height=300,width=400');
```

resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be Hardware acceleration of chrome.
Try following Douglas answer to disable it, [here](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/28qzQgJD2mU/2G73ygk2EsgJ).

Comment: I try this, no reaction.